# Appending subdirectory upon subdirectory

Tags: javascript, url

Using [JavaScript URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), how can I expand upon the subdirectory of an existing URL instance with an additional path?

The goal is to build a URL to generate this:

```
https://api.foo.com/crm/v3/objects/companies/12345
```

I can successfully construct the subdirectory outside the URL by concatenating strings:

```
const objectType = 'companies'
let subDirectory = `/crm/v3/objects/${objectType}`;
// '/crm/v3/objects/companies'

const objectId = '12345';
subDirectory = `${subDirectory}/${objectId}`;
// '/crm/v3/objects/companies/12345'

const urlRequest = new URL(subDirectory, 'https://api.foo.com');
// 'https://api.foo.com/crm/v3/objects/companies/12345'
```

However, if I try to build upon an instance of URL, it modifies the initial subdirectory:

```
const objectType = 'companies';
const subDirectory = `/crm/v3/objects/${objectType}`;
let urlRequest = new URL(subDirectory, 'https://api.foo.com');
// https://api.foo.com/crm/v3/objects/companies

const objectId = '12345';
urlRequest = new URL(objectId, urlRequest.toString());
// 'https://api.foo.com/crm/v3/objects/12345'
// Replaces '.../companies' with '.../12345'
// Not appends to existing subDirectory
// '.../companies/12345'
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this is related to TypeScript at all. This is a JavaScript thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `/` at the end of the sub-directory gives the result you are looking for:

```
const objectType = 'companies';
const subDirectory = `/crm/v3/objects/${objectType}/`;
let urlRequest = new URL(subDirectory, 'https://api.foo.com');

const objectId = '12345';
urlRequest = new URL(objectId, urlRequest.toString());
// https://api.foo.com/crm/v3/objects/companies/12345
```